# changing the company name of application in android studio

Tags: android-studio

when i created the project i have entered "atoa" in the company domain, and now my package name is "atoa.myApplication".i have tried to change it from the manifest and then move it but it didnt work. all the solutions i found are for changing "myApplication" name but i want to change `atoa.myApplication` to `com.myApplication`

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to AndroidManifest file
2. Here, put your cursor over your package name "atoa.myApplication", don't select just place cursor over the word you want to rename (For eg: atoa) and
3. Press shift+F6 you will get a popUp for Renaming your package. Write your new package name and refactor.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Goto App->build.gradle

Change it in there and make sure to resync!

Comment: it give me this build error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.roomates'